# Jetty: set up redirecting to index page in java application except the specified url

Tags: java, rest, jetty

I have a web application written in `Java` and `Javascript` - java part is responsible for `REST API` (jax-rs) and UI is written in javascript. I need to set up redirecting from any not existing URL in the domain e.g.

```
localhost:8080/blabla
```

Except the URLs which are reserved for REST(starting with "rest" in the app)

```
localhost:8080/rest
```

Is there any way to set this up in web.xml etc

Answer (score 0):

Just use the standard path mapping rules to your advantage.

Example:

Setup your RestServlet on the `<url-pattern>/rest</url-pattern>`

Then setup a your SpecialRedirectServlet at the url pattern `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`.

If a request comes in at `/rest` or `/rest/` then it goes to the rest servlet, all other requested paths will goto the default path mapping at `/`